# Google Drive API: we're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries

Tags: google-drive-api

I know this question has been asked multiple times in the last year but I can't seem to get an answer that works.  I am trying to download a file from Google Drive using this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/12BeD3I6JoRMfgeEJfZpZGEGew4Ncpw4i?alt=media&access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMDyh3TTrbXZxSxQkuwj
```

(token shortened for brevity here)

The response is 403 Forbidden with the explanation "We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.".

We are a verified application, and there is no problem accessing file lists and uploading files. We do indeed intend to download files in an automated fashion, but I see this error on the very first try.

I did find another question on this topic where the solution is to use an authorization header.  This is what our headers look like:

```
Host: www.googleapis.com
User-Agent: comaxis-agent/1.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMDyh3TTrbXZxSxQkuwj
```

(Again, token shortened)

This does not work, there is no change.  Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) I think that this is the reason of your issue. So in the current stage, it is required to use the access token in the request header. This has already been mentioned in your question.
- About your following request

  ```
    Host: www.googleapis.com
    User-Agent: comaxis-agent/1.0
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMDyh3TTrbXZxSxQkuwj
  ```

  - `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###?alt=media` is the GET method. In this case, `Content-Type` is not required. And, please modify `bearer` to `Bearer`

When above points are reflected to the curl command, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/12BeD3I6JoRMfgeEJfZpZGEGew4Ncpw4i?alt=media"
```

- When that file is the binary file, the option of `-o filename` might be required.

#### Note:

- When you want to download the files of Google Docs (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on), please use the export method. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document)

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: Yep, it was uppercase "B" instead of "b" - my bad.  Thanks for your help and sorry to bother you.